# Is it sufficient to claim that the limits of $\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}$ and $\frac1x$ must be the same?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I was trying to evaluate this limit [Calculate: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{x^2+2x+3}{x^2+x+1} \right)^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336585/calculate-lim-x-rightarrow-infty-left-fracx22x3x2x1-rightx?rq=1) . After doing long division, I got like everybody else limit as $x$ approaches infinity of $(1+(x+2)/(x^2+x+1))^x$. Would it be a mistake to say that lim as $x$ approaches infinity of $(x+2)/(x^2+x+1)$=lim as x approaches infinity of $1/x$ and just conclude that the answer is $e$? I know I would be right in this situation, but can I approximate things like this in general? Thanks!

Comment: The conditional statement in general is indeed true. But if it's *enough* as an answer, that probably depends on what you can use.

Comment: Applying L'Hopital we get 1/(2x+1), which is about 1/2x, and I know that if it was 2/x the answer would've been $e^2$. So maybe I shouldn't use approximations like this all the time because they are very fragile?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. I'm not sure where you're getting at.

Comment: You wanna solve it another time, Ovi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure you are aware that it is not enough to say that the limit as $x$ goes to infinity of $\frac{1}{x}$ is "the same as" the limit of $\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}$.

However, what you probably meant is that the limit of the **ratio** of the two quantities is $1$. That is,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}}=1.$$
That is enough.

With some experience, one can scan the expression and *see* that for large $x$, $\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}$ "behaves like" $\frac{1}{x}$, and therefore the limit must be $e$. Of course, everything changes if $x^2$ is replaced by $2x^2$.

At this stage of your mathematical development, you would be expected to go through further detail. For example, we can start by noting that the exponent is $\frac{x^2+x+1}{x+2}\frac{x(x+2)}{x^2+x+1}$. Once we have done this sort of thing a few dozen times, then, with some caution, we can begin to take jumps.

Comment: Yes I am aware but I am concerned that the ratio isn't exactly 1. I we apply L'hopital to $(x+2)/(x^2+x+1)$ we get 1/(2x+1), and (1/x)/[1/(2x+1)] is approximately 2.

Comment: Applying L'Hospital to $(x+2)/(x^2+x+1)$ is **not good.**. You want to apply L'H to the ratio I described in the answer. Of course you don't need L'H. Why is it not good? Taking derivatives in L'H style preserves limits, but **not the speed of convergence**.

Comment: Oh ok thanks you good to know